# Unable to call my operator<T t>() if it doesn't receives arguments

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a `State` class that will be used like an enum.

```
template <class ApplicationType>
class State
{
public:

     
    template<class T>
    requires requires(){ std::is_base_of<ApplicationType, T>::value; }
    unsigned int operator()()   //broken operator
    {
        static unsigned int localCounter = counter++;
        return localCounter;
    }

    template<class T>
    requires requires(){ std::is_base_of<ApplicationType, T>::value; }
    unsigned int operator()(T t)   //working operator
    {
        static unsigned int localCounter = counter++;
        return localCounter;
    }

private:
    unsigned int counter = 0;
};
```

My problem is that when I call the first operator `State::operator()()` the code doesn't compile, but when I call the second one `State::operator()(T t)` everything works fine.

```
class Base{};

class Derived: Base{};


int main()
{
    State<Base> myState;
    Derived d;

    myState<Derived>(); // Error
    myState(d);         // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Error message:
expected primary-expression before '>' token
expected primary-expression before ')' token

PS: I'm using G++ with `-std=c++20`

Comment: You can't pass a template argument to templated operators. They must be deducible from the function arguments.

Comment: You could use the syntactic-sugar free form `myState.operator()<Derived>();`, but then you're better off with a reguarly named function.

Comment: @molbdnilo Exactly! I wanted to use just `myState<Derived>()` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the explicit notation for the call:

```
myState.operator()<Derived>();
```